# sublime text customize syntax highlighting

Tags: lua, themes, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3, color-scheme

so I am using Sublime Text 3 for coding in lua, and I found a theme that I really like. I am speaking of the theme "Centurion" with color scheme "Galea (SL)".
There is only one thing that I don't like and I wondered if there is an easy way to fix it:

when I have an if statement like:

```
if not func1() and 1==1 or 2==2 then
```

"if" and "then" are colored red, but "not","and","or" are white like normal text. Is there an easy way to add those to syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. First open the file `Lua.tmLanguage` located in `Packages/Lua`
2. Find the `<dict>` entry containing `<string>\b(and|or|not)\b</string>`
3. Change the the `key` of that entry to `keyword.control.lua`.

That way the and, or and not keywords should be rendered with same color as if, else, etc.

Here is the complete dict entry after modification:

```
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>\b(and|or|not)\b</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>keyword.control.lua</string>
</dict>
```

However this does have some drawbacks, for example this change can be overwritten when you update Sublime Text. I tested it very briefly so there might be some side effects. Try it and let me know in the comments if it works for you.

PS: I tested this on Sublime Text 2, hopefully it will work the same way on Sublime Text 3